# Cannot Create image with packer for GCP (with VM)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtualbox, packer

I want to create image with packer build command but when I do that I face this error :

```
googlecompute: * The user does not have access to service account 'service-76100000418@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  User: 'farzin-second-test-project@farzin-second-test-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account
```

I have added the service account user role and compute admin and Compute Instance Admin (v1) to my service account. 
Also I enabled the compute API ,but in my virtual box I used centos, and here I use this packer build which does not work properly. 
There I create one file with name credentials and put json key in there, and also I make my packer template, I should also say my template is validated.

Does anybody have any Idea? The odd thing is it asks me to give this permission to the user, but still it is not working after adding that.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to enable all fallowing API's on your GCP account:**

```
gcloud services enable sourcerepo.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable compute.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable servicemanagement.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable storage-api.googleapis.com
```

**Also make sure your service account has the proper permissions** (and you are using a proper account):

```
CLOUD_BUILD_ACCOUNT=$(gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT --filter="(bindings.role:roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder)"  --flatten="bindings[].members" --format="value(bindings.members[])")

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT \
  --member $CLOUD_BUILD_ACCOUNT \
  --role roles/editor
```

You may also have a look at the documentation : [Building VM images using Packer](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/building/build-vm-images-with-packer) and [Create a Cloud Build image factory using Packer](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/create-cloud-build-image-factory-using-packer).

Comment: I have done All of the before and checked APIs and All of the aew enabled also But i didnt use command instead go to console and add roles to my account and user but it doesnt work

Comment: Can you provide a list of steps you've taken and when the error occurs ?

Comment: I have  enabled and checked all of the mentioned APIs also I go to console and service account and I makeservice account and add both compute admin and comute instance admin beta(v1) and service acoount user and then I aded my user and also I add other permission to one role and add that role to my service account

Comment: Then I go to my VB and there I run packer build command andthere I face error that mentione :the service account (which is made by google) and my user (my user do not have permission to access to service account that created by google) and ask owner to give service account access role to user

Comment: Do you have a `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` attached to your service account ?

Comment: Yes I have it,I added this role too

Comment: I will try to duplicate your issue - what version of CentOS you're using ?

Comment: I believe at this point it's a good idea to contact 1:1 support. You clearly have permissions problem and I can't solve this nor verify you have the correct ones.

Comment: from whom can i get 1:1 support?